# Connecting and Fetching a record form sequel server 2005

Tags: c++, api, visual-c++, winapi

I have a windows application in visual C++. I am not using MFC, in this application I have connect to SQL server 2005 and fetch records form a database file. Can any one guide me how this can done. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say, you could use some wrapper framework around the odbc calls. Currently I was working on a project where SQL server communication was involved so I found this wrapper framework: [TinyODBC](http://code.google.com/p/tiodbc/) which is a minimalistic ODBC wrapper library. It's pretty trivial how can one use it, but I have to admit I had to patch it for a little more functionality. But otherwise it is a useful choice of ODBC communication. Now, you can use the native SQL driver via ODBC. Since it's a minimal framework, if you go through the tutorial you'll be ready to create new application with it.
Now

Answer (score 0):

The complete list of accessing methods is listed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc765421.aspx). Most popular choices for C++ programmers are SQL Server Native Client and MDAC/Windows DAC, both support OLEDB and ODBC interfaces. A comparison of SQL Server Native Client and MDAC/WIndows DAC is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131035.aspx).

There are other wrappers built on top of OLEDB and ODBC such as ADO or TynyODBC, which can help you to write more readable code.